# Changing Canvas Removes Image

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

I'm using a HTML canvas in a similar way to a t-shirt editor, allowing users to position and resize an image. The image is drawn onto the canvas like so:

```
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload = function () {
    var ratio = img.width / img.height;

    imageWidth = canvas.width;
    imageHeight = imageWidth / ratio;
    imageY = (canvas.height-imageHeight)/2;
    if (imageHeight > canvas.height) {
        imageHeight = canvas.height;
        imageWidth = imageHeight * ratio;
        imageY = 0;
    }

    imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
    imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
    draw(true, false);
}

function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    if (withAnchors) {
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
    }

    if (withBorders) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}
```

The actual image that is drawn onto the canvas is set using PHP on my main index.php file, as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> img.src = <?php echo json_encode($image_url); ?>; </script>
```

The canvas is a different size depending on the product, I'm dynamically changing the size of the canvas when the user changes the product like so:

```
var changeCanvas = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
canvas.width = 71;
canvas.height = 285;
```

My problem is whenever I change the size of the canvas, the image drawn onto it disappeared. However it strangely reappears whenever I click or move over the canvas. I'm wondering what I am doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

---

Mouse actions:

```
$("#editorCanvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#editorCanvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#editorCanvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#editorCanvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. The [standard states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#2dcontext) (my emphasis):

> When the user agent is to set bitmap dimensions to width and height,
>   it must run the following steps:
>
> [...]
>
> - Resize the scratch bitmap to the new width and height and **clear it to fully transparent black.**

All content must be redrawn after canvas changes size.

You probably have (although not currently shown) added mouse event listeners which triggers a redraw.

Code for redrawing the image using the draw function: `draw(true, false);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have actually got mouse actions, but they're actually allowing for the repositioning and resizing of the image drawn on the canvas. I've added the mouse actions to my questions above - but i've actually tried to redraw the image when the canvas size is changed with no luck?

Comment: @AlexSaidani did you try to call the draw() method after the size is set? (in the same operation, like you do in the onload handler)

Comment: Yep I tried to completely redraw the image using the entire image.onload function with no luck, however by just using my main draw function i've managed to get it working: draw(true, false);